# ¿Cómo mostrar valor de campo personalizado de producto variable en Woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

¡Hola!

He estado intentando mostrar el valor de un campo personalizado de un producto variable con

```
get_post_meta();
```

sin embargo no he tenido éxito, a continuación describo a detalle el problema:

He agregado un campo personalizado en todos mis productos (modelo) con las siguientes funciones en el archivo **functions.php**:

```
// Campo personalizado
// Añadimos el campo modelo
function campo_personalizado_apg() {
    woocommerce_wp_text_input( array( 
        'id' => 'modelo', 
        'class' => 'wc_input short', 
        'label' => __( 'modelo', 'woocommerce' )
    ) );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_pricing', 'campo_personalizado_apg' );

// Añadimos el campo UPC (variables)
function campo_personalizado_variable_apg( $loop, $datos_de_variacion, $variacion ) {
    echo PHP_EOL . "<div>";
    woocommerce_wp_text_input( array( 
        'id' => 'modelo[' . $variacion->ID . ']', 
        'class' => 'wc_input short', 
        'label' => __( 'modelo', 'woocommerce' ),
        'value' => get_post_meta( $variacion->ID, 'modelo', true ),
        'style' => 'display:block;', 
    ) );
    echo "</div>" . PHP_EOL;
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_after_variable_attributes', 'campo_personalizado_variable_apg', 10, 3 );

//Actualiza los valores introducidos en cada campo
function guarda_campos_personalizados_apg( $product_id ) { 
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) {
        return;
    }
    if ( isset( $_POST['modelo'] ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $product_id, 'modelo', $_POST['modelo'] );
    } else {
        delete_post_meta( $product_id, 'modelo' );
    }
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'guarda_campos_personalizados_apg' );

//Actualiza los valores introducidos en cada campo
function guarda_campos_personalizados_variable_apg( $product_id ) { 
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) {
        return;
    }
    if ( isset( $_POST['modelo'][$product_id] ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $product_id, 'modelo', $_POST['modelo'][$product_id] );
    } else {
        delete_post_meta( $product_id, 'modelo' );
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_save_product_variation', 'guarda_campos_personalizados_variable_apg', 10, 2 );
```

Muestro el valor en cualquier archivo ***.php** con las siguientes líneas de código:

```
    if ($product->is_type('variable')) {
        echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'modelo', true);
        var_dump(get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'modelo', true));

    } else {
        echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'modelo', true);
    }
```

En los productos simples el valor del campo se muestra sin ningún problema.

```
Modelo: p5r.2
```

El problema reside cuando quiero mostrar el valor del campo en un producto variable(el valor del campo es distinto por cada variación):

La línea de código:

```
get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'modelo', true);
```

Imprime:

```
array
```

La línea de código:

```
var_dump(get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'modelo', true));
```

Imprime:

```
array(3) { [4299]=> string(3) "p5r.3" [4300]=> string(3) "p5r.4" [4301]=> string(3) "p5r.5" }
```

¿Alguien puede ayudarme a que se imprima unicamente el valor del campo correspondiente en los productos variables?

Gracias.

Answer (score -1):

Buenos dias:
por lo que entiendo te muestra un vector con los valores de todas las variaciones, no?
Parece que estas actuando sobre el producto padre, no sobre los hijos (variaciones).
Tendras que obtener el indice de la variacion que quieres mostrar y sacar el valor correspondiente (key en PHP) de tu campo personalizado.

Comment: Si bien esto puede ser una respuesta correcta, sería ideal si pudieras indicar mejor qué cambios y dónde deben hacerse en el código compartido por el usuario.